# Creating docker-consul official image

Tags: docker, certificate, consul

I am trying to use the official docker-consul image reading this documentation https://hub.docker.com/_/consul/

Not sure if I can pull this official image from the hub, but I am trying to build the image from the dockerfile and the script in the official repo

https://github.com/hashicorp/docker-consul

using the following command

```
docker build -t docker-consul:0.6 .
```

from teh folder conatining Dockerfile and docker-entrypoint.sh

But image creation fails with the following error

```
   The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache ca-certificates gnupg &&     gpg --recv-keys 91A6E7F85D05C65630BEF18951852D87348FFC4C &&     mkdir -p /tmp/build &&     cd /tmp/build &&     wget 


https://releases.hashicorp.com/docker-base/${DOCKER_BASE_VERSION}/docker-base_${DOCKER_BASE_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip &&     wget 

https://releases.hashicorp.com/docker-base/${DOCKER_BASE_VERSION}/docker-base_${DOCKER_BASE_VERSION}_SHA256SUMS &&     wget 

https://releases.hashicorp.com/docker-base/${DOCKER_BASE_VERSION}/docker-base_${DOCKER_BASE_VERSION}_SHA256SUMS.sig &&     gpg --batch --verify docker-base_${DOCKER_BASE_VERSION}_SHA256SUMS.sig docker-base_${DOCKER_BASE_VERSION}_SHA256SUMS &&     grep ${DOCKER_BASE_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip docker-base_${DOCKER_BASE_VERSION}_SHA256SUMS | sha256sum -c &&     unzip docker-base_${DOCKER_BASE_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip &&     cp bin/gosu bin/dumb-init /bin &&     wget 

https://releases.hashicorp.com/consul/${CONSUL_VERSION}/consul_${CONSUL_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip &&     wget 

https://releases.hashicorp.com/consul/${CONSUL_VERSION}/consul_${CONSUL_VERSION}_SHA256SUMS &&     wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/consul/${CONSUL_VERSION}/consul_${CONSUL_VERSION}_SHA256SUMS.sig &&     gpg --batch --verify consul_${CONSUL_VERSION}_SHA256SUMS.sig consul_${CONSUL_VERSION}_SHA256SUMS &&     grep consul_${CONSUL_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip consul_${CONSUL_VERSION}_SHA256SUMS | sha256sum -c &&     unzip -d /bin consul_${CONSUL_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip &&     cd /tmp &&     rm -rf /tmp/build &&     apk del gnupg &&     rm -rf /root/.gnupg' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

What have I missed?

I want to modify the entrypoint to include the run time parameters for it to run as a standalone mode. And then run the conatiner only using 'docker run consul.

Comment: Did you try docker 'docker pull consul' ? Any specific reason for building from docker file ?

Comment: Thank You!!! I might have been just blind not seeing the image name!

Comment: Actually I do have a requirement to modify the dockerfile

Comment: I just edited the question with my  requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change one file the better way is to prepare your Dockerfile and inherited from official.

Example of Dockerfile:

```
FROM consul:0.6
ADD docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
```

Maybe for you is enough to change only CMD

```
FROM consul:0.6
CMD ["agent", "-your_param_1", "-your_param_2"]
```

Comment: Thanks I endd up doing the exact same thing :)